# Opening .png.aux.xml file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, import, xml, png

I received a *.png.aux.xml* file. I have tried to read it with the GDAL translator and by making a URL from the code. I haven't been able to open the file in QGIS.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `.aux.xml` file contains only metadata about the associated `png` (you can inspect it by opening it in a text editor).

Comment: Did you get the .png as well as the .png.aux.xml?

Comment: Okay thanks Matt. I didn't know it was only metadata. I found a gist online (Github) for converting code (containing metadata for a symbology in that case) found within a .xml file into a URL code. Then the same creator of the gist (in a youtube tutorial) was able to import that symbology info into QGIS using the URL he created. So I assumed something similar could be done?....Here's the link to the tutorial I mentioned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZW97unRBRw ....btw I didn't receive the png file or any other files. Just the .aux.xml

Comment: The xml in that gist is a qgis style file. Your png.aux.xml is completely different and is only useful if you have the actual data (the .png file).

Comment: thanks, user2856